# JSX not returning expected HTML

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in my React component's return statement:

```
return (
        <div>
            {
                props.photos.length > 0 &&
                    <div>
                    {props.photos.map((photo) => 
                        <div>
                            <a target="_blank"
                                href="/api/game_theory/game-files/{this.props.profileId}/files/{photo.id}/{photo.downloadName}">
                                {photo.title}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    )}
                    </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
```

It renders without errors, however the anchor tag looks like this in the HTML:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/api/game_theory/game-files/{this.props.profileId}/files/{photo.id}/{photo.downloadName}">
                                ActualPhotoName.jpg
                            </a>
```

So photo.title is being written out correctly, but photo.id, photo.downloadName, and this.props.profileId are not.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong and I'd appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole `href` inside `{ }` and remove it from the props:

`href={"/api/game_theory/game-files/" + this.props.profileId + "/files/" + photo.id + "/photo.downloadName"}`

Answer (score 2):

You can't "double-interpret" javascript with brackets in JSX.  Assuming your props are available to you, try using ES6 string interpolation:

```
href=`/api/game_theory/game-files/${this.props.profileId}/files/${photo.id}/${photo.downloadName}`>
```

Comment: so I wrapped the href value inside the ticks and added the dollar signs but I get this error when loading: "JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text"

Comment: Put `{ }` around the entire expression like in my answer